# Moving two different objects with two fingers SpriteKit

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, sprite-kit

I want to move two different objects with two fingers . The problem is that I can't use touchBegan method because of I can't recognize which object I currently operate. The best way is to use gesture recognizers because of I can recognize view that I currently dragging, I can move two or more different objects and I always have refference to them. But I can't use gesture recognizers with SpriteKit.I can't add gestures to my objects but I can add gestures to main SKView , but it will work only with one touch object. So, the question is how can i move two different objects with SpriteKit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by adding `SKViews` to `-(void)didMoveToView:` method, and add standart UIGestureRecognizes to this `SKViews`

Answer (score 0):

The touches... methods sure can be used for this. Just for example, to pan multiple sprites, first iterate over the touches. For each one, ask the scene for all the nodes at that point. (This is node you can get a reference to your objects)

Then iterate over all the nodes at that point. If they pass some sort of movability test (lets say by name) use arithmetic to determine their new positions based on the current and previous touch locations of the UITouch object. That being said, the code below will move any sprite on your scene with the name "nameOfMovableObject" along with the touch at that location.

```
CG_INLINE CGPoint CGPointFromPreviousCoords(CGPoint affectedPoint, CGPoint currentPoint, CGPoint previousPoint) {
    return CGPointMake(affectedPoint.x + currentPoint.x - previousPoint.x, affectedPoint.y + currentPoint.y - previousPoint.y);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];

        for (SKNode *node in [self nodesAtPoint:location]) {
            if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"nameOfMovableObject"]) {
                [node setPosition:CGPointFromPreviousCoords(node.position, location, previousLocation)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, i was trying something similar, but it creates a new problem. If i move object very fast , then [self nodesAtPoint:] will not be forced on my object. Also there is a line that my objects must not cross, and when I crossed this line with my finger , obect stands near it, but when i move my finger back out of line then this object must move along with my finger as it was. But touches methods does not contain refferences to my objects, they only search objects with location

Comment: @IgorPrusyazhnyuk It's not a drop in solution. Those are just extra conditions that you'll have to accommodate for. You'll need to figure out a way to store references to these location offsets and your sprites if they're giving you problems.

Comment: I know, and I was trying to solve this by adding my objects into array when touch occures, then move them with touchMoved: from array and to remove them from array with touchEnded: . But it seems unreal because of there can be more than two touches, and I don't know how to tie touch with object. As I said, gestures will be perfect solution, but I don't understand why Apple did not add gestures to SpriteKit objects, arhh.. Must be some way